# Strip trailing decimal points from floats in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datagram

All columns in my dataset seem to be floats. 
Some contain values like like '20. ' or '11. '

How can I selectively and quickly remove the dot and space, without affecting the other values in the column, like '24.4' or '12.5'?

I have tried several solutions but none of them worked.

My goal is to change, for example, '12. ' to '12', for each value in each cell where '. ' appears.

Comment: I highly doubt this is the case, but if you could show us your data, that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to do that with replace ie

```
df.replace('\.(?!\d)','',regex=True)
```

If you have a dataframe like.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['12.','13.','14.1','15.5'])
df.replace('\.(?!\d)','',regex=True) # inplace = True if you want to change main dataframe.
```

```
      0
0  12  
1  13  
2  14.1
3  15.5
```

Comment: They're not strings, they're floats.

Comment: He said 'quickly remove the dot and space' ,which I hope might be strings

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom float formatting function for pandas, for example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 2, 3], 'col2':[2.0, 1.0, 4.1]})
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: ('%f' % x).rstrip('.0'))
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     1
2     3   4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column contain string  :

```
>>> a
   0     1
0  1  12. 
1  2  14.5
2  3  15. 
3  4  16.3
>>> a[1]=[i.replace('. ', '') for i in a[1]]
>>> a
   0     1
0  1    12
1  2  14.5
2  3    15
3  4  16.3
```

if there are float you can create a new list with mixed type (int and float) :

```
>>> b=[int(i) if i.is_integer() else float(i) for i in a[1]]
>>> b
[12, 14.5, 15, 16.3]
```

but you can't do it in the data frame :

```
>>> a[1]=[int(i) if i.is_integer() else float(i) for i in a[1]]
>>> a
     0     1
0  1.0  12.0
1  2.0  14.5
2  3.0  15.0
3  4.0  16.3
```